# Increment counter firestore vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have an attribute in my firebase, that needs to increment when a registration is added. The adding of a registration works, but I can't seem to figure out, how I can increment the quantity dynamically, when a registration occurs.
My initial code for this is:

```
countExperience() {
  db
    .collection("experiences")
    .doc(this.$route.params.experience_id)
    .update({ quantity: + 1 })
    .then(docRef => {
      console.log("added quantity");
    });
},
```

My problem is that the "update" isn't working, and it's basically setting the value to 1, instead of incrementing it.

This is the working code:

```
countExperience() {
  const exp_ref = db.collection("experiences").doc(this.$route.params.experience_id)

  return db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(exp_ref).then(doc => {
      const newCount = doc.data().quantity +1
      t.update(exp_ref, {quantity: newCount})
    })
  })
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the value of `quantity` out of the document, increment it, then write it back.  What you have right now just writes the value in the document without reading it first.

You'll typically want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to do this, so that it all happens in a transactional way.

Comment: I did try that, I might've not written it right at the time

Comment: This was the example I tried to follow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters